# Two divs in td, make div appear above the other and both below the td

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three divs inside a td. One for the text in the td, and the other two are two boxes, one for errors and one for information. The boxes shall not always be shown. In case of just one of them shows, I want them to appear below the td. But in case both of them shows, I want the information box to appear above the error box, but both still below the td. Problem is, they are appearing the exact same position. How can I fix this?

```
<table style="width:350px">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true"></div>
      <div class="infoBox box" contenteditable="false">InfoBox</div>
      <div class="errorBox box" contenteditable="false">ErrorBox</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
.box {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltgc0usn/2/

Comment: remove ```position: absolute```, and to toggle between the css(hide and show) you need javascript.

Comment: I know about how to show them. Removing position: absolute positions them correctly, but makes them appear inside the td which I don't want.

Comment: that's because you are placing them in the same table-row as the data

Comment: Put the two info/error boxes into another div. Position that div absolutely and position the info/error boxes relatively. Of course, when the info box is empty you'll want to make sure it has display: none;

Comment: A Haworth: Exactly what I needed, thanks!